# SQL Enum Error 1064

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a table in a MySQL database, I am not sure where I am going wrong with my syntax. In my query it is returning a 1064 error in the line where I use ENUM. Here is part of my query:

```
CREATE TABLE General
 (
    pId varchar(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    Hometown varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    Year char(2) NOT NULL ENUM("FR","SO","JR","SR")
    Position varchar(2) NOT NULL ENUM("PG","SG","SF","PF","C"),
    Season char(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 2016,
    Date_Of_Birth DATE NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY (pId));
```

Comment: It's either `varchar` or `enum` - not both

Comment: So would I not want to use the ENUM clause in this situation if I wanted to limit input to this column as only the parameters in the parenthesis?

Comment: If you want to use enum, then don't use varchar.

Comment: You really should consider using a tool to generate these and examine the output.

Comment: Using a tool like HeidiSQL, MySQL-Workbench or PhpMyAdmin is probably the easiest way to learn DDL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

missing comma , enum don't need  type, season is a string '2016'  and remove constraint for primary key

```
  CREATE TABLE General
   (
      pId varchar(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
      Hometown varchar(30) NOT NULL,
      Year  ENUM("FR","SO","JR","SR"), <----  here missing commma 
      Position  ENUM("PG","SG","SF","PF","C"),
      Season char(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '2016',
      Date_Of_Birth DATE NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (pId)
  );
```

Comment: After adding the  comma I was still being given this error:

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ENUM("FR","SO","JR","SR"),
Position varchar(2) NOT NULL ENUM("PG","SG","SF","PF"' at line 5